# What is the こと in いまを去ること20年前?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I encountered the examples of 去る.

- 今を去ること２０年前
- 今を去る２０年前
- 東京を去ること200キロ

If I understand them correctly, they mean a certain amount in space/time away from a particular point. 「今を去る２０年前」makes perfect sense to me, but I am puzzled by the 「こと」 in 「今を去ること２０年前」 and 「東京を去ること200キロ」. What does こと mean here? What role does it have in the phrases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fixed pattern used with a time length, a distance, etc. It sounds dramatic as compared to simple 20分待つと, etc.

- オーブンに入れて待つこと20分、美味しいケーキが焼けました。
  Twenty minutes in the oven and ....
- 自宅を出て車で走ること15km、隣町のショッピングセンターに到着した。
  Fifteen kilometers after leaving home, and ...
- 遡ること2日、この部屋では別の事件が起きていた。
  Two days back, ...
- 考え続けること実に3時間、我々はついにひとつの結論に達した。
- ベルを鳴らすこと10回、いまだに返事はない。

Basically this こと should be a nominalizer, but unfortunately, I could not find this usage in my usual dictionaries, nor could I find this pattern in well-known JLPT learning sites.

Answer (score 2):

Practically speaking, you can take *[clause]* + こと + *[numerical expression]* to mean 'Now I talk about things when I do *[clause]* *[numerical exp]*. It is a rhetoric to arouse listener's attention.

Your Examples:

- 今を去ること20年前 : (Now I talk about) 20 years ago
- 今を去る20年前　: I think this can be think of the version where こと is dropped
- 東京を去ること200キロ : I went 200km from Tokyo, then you know what?, (something interesting should follow)

Also さかのぼること20年(前) means '(Going back) 20 years ago'

Duration:

- 研究すること10年　: I've been investigating for 10 years

Also number of times can be used:

- 繰り返すこと100回 : I repeated it 100 times
- 失敗すること100回 : I failed 100 times

Sorry this doesn't directly answer your question, but こと in these construction does not have concrete meaning, but rather functions as a glue between *[clause]* and *[numerical exp]* so to speak.

===

I found a long discussion (most probably with no conclusion) on this construction.

https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/bbs/phpBB/viewtopic.php?topic=10367&forum=3&start=16